# PHP Overloading, singleton instance

Tags: php, singleton, overloading

I've sort of created my own MVC framework and am curious as to how other frameworks can send properties from the "controller" to the "view". Zend does something along the lines of `$this->view->name = 'value';` My code is:

file: services_hosting.php

```
class services_hosting extends controller {
    function __construct($sMvcName) {
        parent::__construct($sMvcName);

        $this->setViewSettings();
    }

    public function setViewSettings() {        
        $p = new property;
        $p->banner = '/path/to/banners/home.jpg';
    }
}
```

file: controller.php

```
class controller  {
    public $sMvcName = "home";

    function __construct($sMvcName) {
        if ($sMvcName) {
            $this->sMvcName = $sMvcName;
        }

        include('path/to/views/view.phtml');
    }

    public function renderContent() {
        include('path/to/views/'.$this->sMvcName.'.phtml');
    }
}
```

file: property.php

```
class property {

    private $data = array();
    protected static $_instance = null;

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (null === self::$_instance) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
            return $this->data[$name];
        }
    }

    public function __isset($name) {
        return isset($this->data[$name]);
    }

    public function __unset($name) {
        unset($this->data[$name]);
    }

}
```

In my services_hosting.phtml "view" file I have:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->p->banner ?>" />
```

This just does not work. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong or is my logic incorrect? I seem to be going round in circles at the moment. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What does your front controller look like?  I really like the way symfony2 handles this with a response object.   See, http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/http_fundamentals.html

Comment: Overloading and Singleton are often a clashing concept. Consider to drop the Singleton and see if your problem goes away. If you need single object instances of that class, store them in a global variable or global array for the moment.

Comment: @hakre Initially in my .phtml I had:
`$p = property::getInstance();`

then:
`<img src="<?php echo $p->banner ?>" />`

But that didn't work, so I think I don't really need the singleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My front controller looks like this

```
class front {

    private $sMvcName = 'home';

    function __construct() {
        $aUriParts = $this->getUriParts();

        if ($aUriParts[0]) {
            $this->sMvcName = implode("_", $aUriParts);   
        }

        $this->constructController();
    }

    private function constructController() {
        $this->view = new property();
        $sControllerName = $this->sMvcName;
        new $sControllerName($this->sMvcName);
    }

    private function getUriParts() {
        $sUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $sUri = trim($sUri, "/");
        $sUri = str_replace("-", "_", $sUri);
        $aUriParts = explode("/", $sUri);
        return $aUriParts;
    }

}
```

services_hosting.php now looks like this

```
class services_hosting extends controller {

    function __construct($sMvcName) {
        $this->setViewSettings();

        parent::__construct($sMvcName);
    }

    public function setViewSettings() {
        $this->view->banner = '/assets/images/banners/home_02.jpg';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if this works?

In your controller.php you create the view object

```
 function __construct() {
    $this->view = new property();
}
```

Now in our service hosting controller

```
class services_hosting extends controller {
function __construct($sMvcName) {
    parent::__construct($sMvcName);

$this->view->banner = '/path/to/banners/home.jpg';
}
```

}

The banner variable should be accessible in your view file now.

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->banner ?>" />
```

Hope this will work...

Comment: Thanks @Dinesh. I will give this a go later. One question though, do I need to declare $view at the top of the class? e.g. `public $view = null;`

Comment: I don't think its necessary. But I think its good practice to declare the variable. In PHP you have have to assign null.. public $view; will  work.

Comment: Ok, what you suggested didn't work but I've finally fixed it. I now create the view object in my front controller before the services_hosting object is created. Then I set the view settings before contructing the parent controller (i.e. controller.php) Then echo $this->view->banner in the .phtml

Answer (score 0):

```
    <img src="<?php echo $this->p->banner ?>" />
```

implys you are in an instance of a class. You said its an external file so you will likely have something along the lines of

```
  $a = new services_hosting();
```

In this case instead of

```
 $this->banner;
```

you would have

```
$a->banner;
```

Comment: The .phtml file is included by controller.php, which is the parent of services_hosting.php, which instantiates class property `$p = new property;`

I tried:
`$p = property::getInstance();`

then:
`<img src="<?php echo $p->banner ?>" />`

but it didn't work.